# CORS POLICY Accesing springboot websocket from reactjs sockjs-clien

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

Iam using ReactJs as frontend and Spring Boot as backend
using stomp and sockJs
every time i connect to the socket cors policy is displayed

the error is the following :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5433/ws/info?t=1700638752589' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

react js frontend code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client'
import { over } from 'stompjs';
import Stomp from 'stompjs';


var myStompClient = null ;

const ChatRoom = () => {
    //message details,connection details ..
    const [userData,setUserDate] = useState({
        username : "" ,
        recievername: "" ,
        connected : false,
        message: "" 
    })

    //hold all public chats
    const [publicChats,setPublicChats] = useState([]);

    //to set a private message the simplest way is to make a map the username as akey and then this userkey will hold list of messages 
    const[privateChats,setPrivateChats] = useState(new Map);

    //this will hold wehter a chatroom or particular user
    const[tab,setTab] = useState("CHATROOM")

    const handleUserName = (event) =>{
        const {value} = event.target;
        setUserDate({...userData,"username" : value})

    }

    const registerUser = () =>{
        // subscribe to all the channel and connect to the websocket
       
        let mySock  = new SockJS('http://localhost:5433/ws');;
        
        myStompClient = Stomp.over(mySock);


        
        console.log(myStompClient);
        
        myStompClient.connect({},onConnected,onError);


    }

    const onConnected = () =>{
        console.log("enter connected function")
        setUserDate({...userData,"connected":true});
        myStompClient.subscribe('/chatroom/public' , onPublicMessageRecieved); //3rd is for the callback function
        myStompClient.subscribe('/user/' +userData.username+'/private',onPrivateMessage);
        userJoin();
    }

const userJoin =() => {
    let chatMessage = {
senderName : userData.username,
status:'JOIN'

    };
    myStompClient.send('/app/message',{},JSON.stringify(chatMessage));

}


    const  onPublicMessageRecieved = (payload) =>{
let payloadData = JSON.parse(payload.body);
switch(payloadData.status){
    case "JOIN":

    if(!privateChats.get(payloadData.senderName)){
        privateChats.set(payloadData.senderName , []);
        setPrivateChats(new Map(privateChats));
    }

        break;
    case "MESSAGE": publicChats.push(payloadData);
    setPublicChats([...publicChats]);
        break;
}

    }


    const onError = (error) =>{
        console.log("failed");
        console.log(error);
    }



    const onPrivateMessage = (payload) =>{
        let payloadData = JSON.parse(payload.body);
        if(privateChats.get(payloadData.senderName)){
            privateChats.get(payloadData.senderName).push(payloadData);
            setPrivateChats(new Map(privateChats));
        }else{
            let list = [] ;
            list.push(payloadData);
            privateChats.set(payloadData.senderName,list);
            setPrivateChats(new Map(privateChats));

        }


    }


    //functions for buttons
    const handleValue = (event) =>{
        const {value,name} = event.target;
        setUserDate({...userData,[name] : value});

    }


    const sendPublicMessage = () =>{
        if(myStompClient){
            let chatMessage = {
senderName:userData.username,
message:userData.message,
status : 'Message'

            };
            myStompClient.send('/app/message',{},JSON.stringify(chatMessage));
            setUserDate({...userData,"message": ""});
        }

    }



    const sendPrivateMessage = () =>{
        if(myStompClient){
            let chatMessage = {
senderName:userData.username,
recievername : tab,
message:userData.message,
status : 'Message'

            };
if(userData.username !== tab){
    privateChats.get(tab).push(chatMessage);
    setPrivateChats(new Map(privateChats));
} 

            myStompClient.send('/app/private-message',{},JSON.stringify(chatMessage));
            setUserDate({...userData,"message": ""});
        }

    }








  return (
    <div className='container'>
        {/* if connected then show the chat else */}
        {userData.connected?
        <div className='chat-box'>
            <div className='member-list'>
                <ul>
                    <li onClick={()=>{setTab("CHATROOM")} }className={`member ${tab==="CHATROOM" && "ACTIVE"}`} >Chatroom</li>
                    {[...privateChats.keys()].map(
                    (name,index) => (
                        <li onClick={()=>{setTab(name)}} className={`member ${tab===name && "ACTIVE"}`}>{name}</li>

                    ))}
                </ul>
   {tab === "chatroom" &&  <div className='chatContent'>  

   <ul className='chat-messages'>
                        {publicChats.map((chat,index) =>(
                            <li className='message' key={index}>
                                    {chat.senderName !== userData.username && <div className='avatar'>{chat.senderName}</div>}
                                    <div className='message-data'>{chat.message}</div>
                                    {chat.senderName === userData.username && <div className='avatar self'>{chat.senderName}</div>}
                                 </li>

                        ))} 

</ul>     


<div className='send-message'>
    <input type='text' className='input-message' name='message' placeholder='enter public message' value={userData.message} onChange={handleValue}></input>
    <button type='button' className='send button' onClick={sendPublicMessage}>send</button>

</div>
                        
     </div>}

                            {/* if it is not a chatroom */}
                            
     {tab !== "chatroom" &&  <div className='chatContent'>  
     <ul className='chat-messages'>
                        {[...privateChats.get(tab)].map((chat,index) =>(
                            <li className='message' key={index}>
                                    {chat.senderName !== userData.username && <div className='avatar'>{chat.senderName}</div>}
                                    <div className='message-data'>{chat.message}</div>
                                    {chat.senderName === userData.username && <div className='avatar self'>{chat.senderName}</div>}
                                 </li>

                        ))} 

                        </ul>

                        <div className='send-message'>
    <input type='text' className='input-message' name='message' placeholder={`enter private message for ${tab}`} value={userData.message} onChange={handleValue}></input>
    <button type='button' className='send button' onClick={sendPrivateMessage}>send</button>

</div>
                      
                        
     </div>}



            </div>
        </div>    
        :
        <div className='register'>
            <input  id='username' name='username' placeholder='enter the user name' value={userData.username} onChange={handleValue}/>
            <button type='button' onClick={registerUser}>connect</button>
        </div>
    
    }

    </div>
  )
}

export default ChatRoom
```

backend spring boot websocket code:

```
package Configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;



@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class webSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    
    

    @Override
    public  void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
         
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000").withSockJS(); //registers an endpoint ws and allows connections from any origin
        //The withSockJS() method enables SockJS fallback options for browsers that do not support WebSocket directly.
        //Clients will connect to the WebSocket server using this endpoint.
        System.out.println("entered the function1");
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    //register stomp endpoints
    
    
    //configure message broker
    //responsible for routing messages from one client to another.
    
    @Override
    public  void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        //prefix in which the user is sending the data to the server
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app"); //messages sent from the client to the server should start with "/app".// this method defines the prefix that clients should use when sending messages to the server.
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chatroom","/user");//These prefixes represent the different topics or channels to which the server can send messages. //Messages sent to destinations starting with "/chatroom" will be sent to subscribers, and messages sent to destinations starting with "/user" will be routed to specific users.
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");//Messages sent to destinations starting with "/user" will be directed to individual users
        //This is the destination prefix for user-specific destinations. When the server sends a message to a destination that starts with "/user", it indicates that the message is intended for an individual user.
        
    
    }
    


    
    
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

spring boot controller :

```
package Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import Model.MessageModel;



@RestController
public class ChatRoomController {
//create method which recieves the data to chatroom and sends the message to the chatRoom topic

    
    //we can create a dynamic topics with this
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemp;
    //his template simplifies sending messages to WebSocket destinations.
    
    
    //messages sent to the "/app/message" destination will be handled by the receivePublicMessage method.
    
    @MessageMapping("/message") //user must use /app/message since we declare //app to make user comunicate with server
    @SendTo("/chatroom/public") //using the chatroom topic i declared
    //This annotation specifies that the return value of the below mehtod  should be sent to the "/chatroom/public
    private MessageModel recievePublicMessage(@Payload MessageModel messageModel) { //@Payload annotation indicates that the method parameter should be extracted from the payload of the message.
        return messageModel;
        
    }
    
    
    @MessageMapping("/private-message")  //   /app/private-message
    private MessageModel recievePrivateMessage(@Payload MessageModel messageModel) {
        
        
        //to send to diffrenet topic
        simpMessagingTemp.convertAndSendToUser(messageModel.getRecieverName() , "/private", messageModel); //to /user/david/private
        // the first argument is the username of the receiver, the second argument is the destination (in this case, "/private"), and the third argument is the message to be sent.
        
        return messageModel;
        
    }
    
    
//  processing public and private messages. 
//  Public messages are broadcasted to the "/chatroom/public" topic, 
//  and private messages are sent directly to the specified user using the "/private" topic. 
}
```